# Configuring Remote IIS Management and "The specified directory does not exist on the server" Error

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I've previously used remote management for IIS and web deploy for existing sites but I'm now looking at setting up a new server that I purely manage via IIS Remote Management.

I have hit a stumbling block where I cant specify the physical path for the new website. I constantly get "The specified directory does not exist on the server".

The parent path for the physical path will exist (i.e c:\inetpub\sites) but I want to specify a new application directory for each site that is created.

Is there a way to allow remote administrators to do this or is it preferable to do this via powershell remoting?

Thanks.

Comment: Something is wrong, it should be no problem creating a new site via remote management. Just make sure the physical directory you are pointing to does already exist on the server and your user has access to it. Maybe run Process Monitor on the server to see why it fails.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear, can I not let the physical directory be created as well, the Parent Path will exist but not the actual sub directory directory the site will use

Comment: If you add a new site, application or virtual directory in IIS, the physical directory you are pointing to must already exist. That's true whether you are remote or local. If it doesn't, you have to create it outside of IIS Manager first, you can use PowerShell remoting or file shares.